# how to track two keyboard key when they are down at same time

Tags: c#

think user pressed two keys at same time .

I want to be notified of this two keys , not one .

like `Up + Left`

how can I find out this ?

Comment: What kind of project is this? WinForms? WPF? Web?

Comment: do you want to catch the events global or local(when your app is topmost and in use) only ?

Comment: Note also that not all key combinations will work on cheap keyboard hardware, and you will simply not get some key down/key up notifications. (This is a reason why $150+ keyboards exist.) Only Ctrl, Alt and Shift pressed together with a "normal" key will work in all cases. Might be worth remembering this before you tear out your hair debugging your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should register handlers for the keyup and keydown events.

for each key involved in your key combination, you store a flag which tells if the key is up or down. each time you receive a keydown event for one of those keys, you set the flags, each time you receive a keyup event, you reset the flag (set it back to 0).

when all the flags are set, it means that all the keys for the combination are pressed at the same time, you can then call a function of your choice to react on this event.